# Can I independently modify volume levels for 4 different microphones with ZOOM H4n?

Tags: microphone, zoom-h4n, tascam

I'd like to connect 4 microphones to my ZOOM H4n using the technique described in this video:

https://vimeo.com/19134430 - **Short:** Internal microphones are bypassed connecting two microphones to the H4n by using a mini jack which left and right channels are nothing but each of the two microphones' signal in mono.

Is it possible to change every channel's volume independently using the 4CH mode with the H4n?

I don't want to think that my only solution is to get a Tascam DR-60D...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The 1/8" jack has a single gain adjustment.  No left and right adjustment.

Comment: this is very minimal, can you explain this a bit more about the implementation of gain in the zoom?